# How to call Method in another class to the other class and pass it to main

Tags: java

How to call method in another class to other class and pass it to main class

i have Class1.java class that looked like this

```
public class Class1{

    public void callMe() {
        System.out.println("Menambah tabel mahasiswa");
    }

}
```

Then I create another class named `Class2` in a file called `Class2.java` that looked like this

```
public class Class2 {

    private Class1 class1;

    //getset generated by netbeans, skipped

    public void justCallMe(){
        class1.callMe();
    }
}
```

and i want to use the class2 method named `justCallMe()` in main class, that looked like this

```
    Class2 classy = new Class2();
    classy.justCallMe();
```

but it give me error "java.lang.NullPointerException"
I think it cause by wrong passing method from class to class and to main, cause when i try invoke `System.out.println("test")`; in `Class2`, it worked

Comment: ooh my bad, miss type, correction from @Benjamin Gruenbaum, let me try it first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your code.

First of all,

```
Class2 classy = new classy();
```

Should be

```
Class2 classy = new Class2();
```

Since you're creating an instance of `Class2`

Second of all, in the constructor, you need to initialize its `Class1` member, so inside `Class2` you need a constructor that'll do that for you

```
public Class2() {
   class1 = new Class1();
}
```

The `NullPointerException` you received is probably because in your real code you did have `Class2 classy = new Class2();` but did not initialize its `class1` member

Answer (score 0):

You should "new" your class first.

```
Private Class1 class1 = new Class1();
```

Comment: Hi, I'm wondering what advantage in your opinion you think your answer offers over my answer from 5 minutes ago?

Comment: Yours is better since it don't initialize the class when it is not needed.

Comment: that's the point, thanks to both of you, you two have a great answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains many errors. To better understand see the following source code.

First, create a sub class

```
class subclass {
         //Create a method to be called .Here the name is used as Meth

         public void Meth(){
         //Do some work here
         }
```

Then, create a super class containing main method.

```
    class superclass {
           public static void main(String ar[]){
           //Create an object of sub class
           subclass subc = new subclass();
           //To call function to execute its task
           subc.Meth();
}
```

If the sub class is in another package then import that class of that package.